# Java app connecting to SQLite database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, jar

I am developing a very small java application for people on my network. All it does is accept options for user input, grabs data from multiple SQLite databases (no updating to actual database!), and spits out a calculation. It works fine in eclipse but I cannot find a solution for running it as one consolidated application that I can distribute to my coworkers.

I am reading that JDBC is not able to query databases inside jars. I am also reading that it is dangerous and slow to keep the databases on the shared network. Finally, I am told I can create a temporary database when the program runs but I haven't a clue on how get the databases to copy into the temporary ones if the program cannot find them in the first place.

Here is the syntax I am using to access the databases:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlite:src/productLine.db", config.toProperties());
```

The database is located in the src folder. My questions are:

Is it possible (if advisable) to get the runnable jar to read a database inside of it?
Are there alternative options for this sort of problem?
Am I storing my databases properly or should they have their own source folder?

Comment: `java application for people on my network` so why don't you use a RDBMS, like MySQL, on the network instead to distribute a copy of the db to each user ?

Comment: Well my table are relatively small which is why I went with the Lite version. Could you expound on how the network would go about distributing it? I'm not very familiar with database management in general.

Comment: When data is small and you won't update the DB why not put data in plain csv text files and read from resource stream with, say, Scanner ? Some readings about MySQL + JDBC here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html.

Comment: What network file system would you be using?

Comment: Thank you PeterMmm. I mostly wanted to use a database just for the sake of learning. Your solution seems cleaner and more straightforward which I suppose should always be the end goal.

CL, I don't know what file system I am on. We have a small LAN with shared server space. What are you thoughts?